# Почему после запуска он выводит не пароли а <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001F9F6034F90>

Tags: python

```
from typing import Optional

class BaseGenerator:
    def reset(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def generate(self) -> Optional[str]:
            raise NotImplementedError
class BruteForceGenerator(BaseGenerator):
    def __init__(self, alphabet='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.base = len(self.alphabet)
        self.n = 0
        self.length = 0

    def reset(self):
        self.i = 0

    def generate(self):
        password = ''
        temp = self.n
        while len(password) < self.length:
            rest = temp % self.base
            temp = temp // self.base
            password = self.alphabet[rest] + password

        if password == self.alphabet[-1] * self.length:
            self.length += 1
            self.n = 0
        else:
            self.n += 1
        return password
g = BruteForceGenerator()
print(g.generate() for i in range(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `g.generate() for i in range(1000)` - это генератор, а не ваши пароли.
Решение:

```
g = BruteForceGenerator()
for i in range(1000):
    print(g.generate())
```

Другое решение (`sep='\n'` нужен, чтобы каждый пароль выводился с новой строки):

```
g = BruteForceGenerator()
print(*(g.generate() for i in range(1000)), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Ещё можно обернуть его в квадратные скобки: `[g.generate() for i in range(1000)]`, так python сразу сделает список.

Comment: Или преобразовать в `list`.

Comment: @Vestalt можно, но это требует память, что может вызвать определенные трудности при больших `n` в `range(n)`.